# How can a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space not be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers, real-numbers

How can $V = \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\c & d\\ \end{pmatrix} \ \ |\ \ \  a,b,c,d \in \mathbb {C} \ \ and \ \ a+d \in \mathbb{R}\end{Bmatrix} $ be a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and at the same time not a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space?

If it were an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, would it not also be an $\mathbb {C}$-vector space because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, so every $a,b,c,d$ could be written as $a + 0 \cdot i$, $b + 0 \cdot i$, ...?

Comment: Being a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space means you should be able to scalar multiply by *any* complex number.  How do you define $i\left( \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1-i \end{matrix}\right)$?

Comment: That would be \begin{pmatrix} -1 + i & 0 \\0 & 1+i\\ \end{pmatrix} which is complex, isn't it?

Comment: @Bobface, $(-1+i) + (1+i) = 2i\not\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah ok, so the condition $a+d \in \mathbb{R}$ also has to be met in the result, not just in the definition?

Comment: Just because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ does not mean that an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space is also a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space. That's a fallacious conclusion.

Comment: @Bobface: A very similar question was asked recently in chat by user Mary Star; are you two acquainted?

Comment: Nope.. I don't know him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $\Bbb R$-vector space, the scalar product $\lambda v$ with $\lambda\in \Bbb C$ **isn't defined**. You can *define* a [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification) of a $\Bbb R$-vector space, but it will be *another* structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is isomorphic, *as an abelian group*, to $\mathbf C^4$. However it cannot be a $\mathbf C$-vector space for the very simple following reason:

Matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ are characterised by the fact that its diagonal elements $a$ and $d$ are conjugate.

Now if $d=\overline a$,and if we multiply the matrix by, say, $1+i$, we have 
$$ (1+i)d=(1+i)\overline a\neq\overline{(1+i)a}. $$